# What is the definition of DDR memory latency?

Tags: ddr, latency

On [Corsair's web site](https://www.corsair.com/us/en/explorer/diy-builder/memory/is-speed-or-latency-more-important-when-choosing-ram/), they define memory latency with an equation:

> (Real Latency) = CAS Latency x 2000 / Data-rate

My question is what that means in practice. Is this the delay from the time the address is put on the DDR's bus until the first read comes back?

From the CPU point of view, intra-chip, registers are available in under a clock cycle, but the RAM value still has to propagate through the cache, the buffers at pins.

What is the latency for Intel or AMD processors of current generation after the value. There is latency from the chipset, and presumably from the CPU itself.

Comment: You'd have to specify the type of latency before it would have a specific definition.  That link for example talks about CAS latency, which is the delay after a read operation in some circumstances. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAS_latency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CAS latency stands for Column Access Strobe latency. It’s a timing
> parameter that measures the delay between the memory controller
> sending a command to read data from a specific column in the memory
> module and the module responding with the requested data. CAS latency
> is measured in clock cycles, which are determined by the memory
> module’s frequency.

Source: https://www.globalonetechnology.com/blog/what-is-cas-latency-for-memory-modules/

The total time it will take to make a memory operation will be determined by the time it takes for the data to get to/from the memory, which will be determined by the memory clock. The memory has to process that operation and then sends the data back.

I think they have this wrong because for the read operation to complete  it should take the CAS time plus the time it takes to send the data (which would be the bus clock length * amount of data in the read operation)

Comment: If I'm hitting a new memory location (new row and column, it should be RAS + CAS, right?

Comment: Yes, you need to select the row then the column.